# The text in UISearch bar disappears after i click outside

Tags: ios, swift, filter, searchbar

I am new to Swift. The problem I am facing is in the Search bar. If I am entering the text, the search is happening. But as soon as I click outside the search bar text disappear with the filtered table view. I want to retain the text so that even if the user enters anything wrong, he should understand the search text.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
{


    var temp : String?

    temp = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "tagsareselected") as? String

    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == ""
    {
        print("is searching is not working")
        issearching = false
        view.endEditing(true)
    }


    else if (temp == "0")
    {
    issearching = true

        print("Searching is working")
        filtercards = card.filter({ (card : Cards) -> Bool in
            let didmatch = ((card.name.lowercased().hasPrefix(searchBar.text!.lowercased())) || (card.company.lowercased().hasPrefix(searchBar.text!.lowercased())) ||  (card.email.lowercased().hasPrefix(searchBar.text!.lowercased())) ||  (card.city.lowercased().hasPrefix(searchBar.text!.lowercased())) ||  (card.designation.lowercased().hasPrefix(searchBar.text!.lowercased())) ||  (card.phone.lowercased().hasPrefix(searchBar.text!.lowercased())))

            return didmatch
        })
    }
    cardsTable.reloadData()
}
```

How can I retain the text even after the user clicks outside with filter `table view`?

Comment: are you added the any gesture in your view

Comment: I have added refresh controller to reload the data.

Comment: can you add some additional code or relevant info related this.

Comment: This is all I am using for search.

Comment: is this possible to attach your project

Comment: Sorry i cant do that.

Comment: By any chance have you implemented searchbar's delegate method `searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {}`?

Comment: I have not implemented searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {}.